# cannot set property 'nometape' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular7 and I'm having an issue with the code "cannot set property 'nometape' of undefined". I'm using an interface "Process" that contains an array of objects "Etape" and I think I have a problem with the initialization.
the interfaces are :

```
export interface Process {
    id : string,
    etapes : Etape[],
} 
export interface Etape {
    nomEtape : string,
    ordre : number,
    etat : number,
    remarque : string,
    duree: string;
    dateRDV : Date,
}
```

The declaration of the object is :

```
  proEdit : Process = {
  id: "",
  etapes : [] 
}
```

And in the constructor I initialize the process etapes array :

```
this.proEdit.etapes = [{
         nomEtape : " ",
         ordre : 0,
         etat : 0,
         remarque : "",
         duree: "",
         dateRDV : new Date(),
       }] ;
```

The loop on the etapes array generates this issue : cannot set property 'nometape' of undefined

````
editProcess(){
   for(let i = 0; i < this.productForm.value.etapes.length; i++) {
     this.proEdit.etapes[i].nomEtape = this.productForm.value.etapes[i]["step"];
   } ```
````

Comment: What's the value of `this.productForm.value.etapes.length`? It may possibly be that the length of `this.productForm.value.etapes` is more than the length of `this.proEdit.etapes`, and the error you are getting happens when `productForm` goes over `proEdit` length.

Comment: Can you share the details of this.productForm?

Comment: The productForm is a FormGroup with a dynamic length. Even when i put the proEdit.etapes length with the same length as this.productForm.value.etapes it returns a problem in the last element : Cannot create property 'nomEtape' on number '4'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that your problem isn't related to the initialization as you mentioned. I'd say the issue is that the array at index of `i` is undefined. Did you push a new Etape object into `this.proEdit.etapes`?

Can you try something like this instead? Not sure if this will work but the idea is to push a new element into the array. Dont just set the value at index of i, because there's nothing there to begin with.

```
const newEtape: Etape = {
  nomEtape : this.productForm.value.etapes[i]["step"],
  ordre : 0,
  etat : 0,
  remarque : "",
  duree: "",
  dateRDV : new Date(),
};

this.proEdit.etapes.push(newEtape);
```

Comment: Thank you. So I need to create a new Etape object each time I need to push a new value into the proEdit.etapes array .

Comment: Yes, if it's being added to the array for the first time. Otherwise, you can use the Array helper methods such as filter, find, forEach to locate and update an existing Etape object in your array.

Answer (score 0):

Your initialization code for `this.proEdit.etapes` only puts one element in the array.  So, if `this.productForm.value.etapes` has more than one element, then you will get this error.

I'd be inclined to put a method on whatever lives in proEdit that can sync an array of step values to its internal etapes array.

Something like this code (that assumes you have lodash zip or similar):

```
const makeNewEtape = (step: string, etape: Etape | Object = {}): Etape => ({
  // default values
  ordre : 0,
  etat : 0,
  remarque : "",
  duree: "",
  dateRDV : new Date(),

  // override defaults with existing Etape values
  ...etape,

  // Override any existing nomEtape value
  nomEtape : step,

});

class ProSteps {
    private etapes: Etape[] = [ makeNewEtape(" ") ];

    syncEtapes(steps: string[]) {
      this.etapes = zip(this.etapes, steps)
        .filter(([ , step]:[ Etape,string]) => !!step)
        .map(([etape, step]:[Etape, string] ) => makeNewEtape(step, etape));
    }

    getEtapes() { // don't leak the array
      return [...this.etapes]
    }
}

const ps = new ProSteps();
ps.syncEtapes([ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz']);
```

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-lodash-playground-tdhboj?embed=1&file=index.ts) you can play with.